# How can I make a real from a list of digits?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

The following code will join all the numbers together as an integer:

```
ToExpression @ StringJoin[ToString /@ a]
```

> `123456789`

How can I get a real, for example `12.3456789`?

In this example, the separation point is at position `N = 2` from the left.  I want my code to work for any arbitrary `N`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't what you're after is a **rational**? Yes, all rationals are contained in the reals, but that's beside the point. And since a great majority of real numbers are limits of infinite convergent sequences, they have infinite digits, thus cannot be built nor expressed numerically accurately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
FromDigits[{a, 2.}]
(* 12.3457 *)
```

and before you ask, the number was not cut, it's just not displayed per default

```
FullForm[%]
(* 12.3456789` *)
```

Comment: That's really clever.

Comment: It almost seems the documentation for `RealDigits` has more useful information on input forms for `FromDigits` than the doc for `FromDigits` itself ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this?

```
num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

res = ToExpression@StringJoin[ToString /@ num];

toreal[b_, n_] := AccountingForm[b/10.^n, {9, n}]

toreal[res, #] & /@ Range@8 // TableForm
```

[image]